# AWS App runner build fail: pkg-config not found when building wheel for pycairo in django project

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, pycairo, amazon-app-runner

I am trying to deploy a django project to AWS App runner and it uses xhtml2pdf which needs pycairo in its dependency. It works locally I believe because I am running ubuntu, which is labeled this as "pkg-config" but since AWS App runner is running a different distro where it recognizes "pkgconfig". I tried to change the export path but that did not seem to work. The error is listed below

[Image of output from AWS app runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T57hF.png)

I also tried to run the following commonds
`yum install pkgconfig`
but it was already installed. I also tried
`yum install cairo`
but it also already installed. It seems like the packages are there before running requirements.txt but it cant find it.

[UPDATE]
The programs works locally, but since I do not have access to a CLI for app runner (or i do not know how to access it), it makes it much harder to determine what path pkgconfig is on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do hit and trail like running commands in apprunner.yaml (If you are building using that).

```
version: 1.0
runtime: python3
build:
  commands:
    build:
    - echo "#######################"
    - pkg-config --version
    - echo "-----------------------"
    - yum install pkgconfig -y
    - echo "-----------------------"
    - echo "#######################"
```